# strtok() вернуть все что находится между кавычками как один токен

Tags: c, строки, token, strtok

Здравствуйте! Есть строка: `test test1 "test2 and test3"`. Как с помощью функции `strtok()`, все что между кавычек, считать как один токен? Тоесть должны получится токены `test`, `test1` и `test2 and test3`. Хороший пример - BASH. В нем это как-то реализовано и если ты не закрыл кавычки, когда нажимаешь enter, запрашивает ввод дальше. Как это сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вам нужно написать мини-парсер. Это не так сложно, кстати. Подумайте об escape-последовательностях (`\\`?), наверняка вам захочется их поддерживать.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Может свой аналог `strtok()` написать?

Comment: Можно. Но лучше, наверное, аналог [`strtok_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok), это более безопасный вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это невозможно.
По крайней мере без вложенных вызовов `strtok`.

Кстати, обратите внимание, что `strtok()` необратимо изменяет свой аргумент (пишет нули после очередного возвращаемого токена).

В качестве альтернативы strtok могу обратить внимание на [strtos](http://pastebin.com/6XBP0KZH)
(документация (как, собственно, и всегда :)) отсутствует, но ничего сложного там нет, думаю, разберетесь).